# Pattern matching and constructors

Tags: functional-programming, pattern-matching, ocaml

Why do i get errors when I write this kind of pattern matching :

```ocaml
type t = A of int | B of float

let f = function
        | (A i | B f) -> true
        | _ -> false
```

or

```ocaml
let f = function
        | A i | B f -> true
        | _ -> false
```

> **Error: Variable f must occur on both sides of this | pattern**

```ocaml
let f = function
        | (A i | B i) -> true
        | _ -> false
```

or

```ocaml
let f = function
        | A i | B i -> true
        | _ -> false
```

> **Error: This pattern matches values of type ints of type float**
>          **but a pattern was expected which matches value**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you provide a single right-hand side for multiple patterns (as you do), OCaml requires that the patterns consistently bind to pattern variables.

In the first situation,

```
match ... with
  | A i | B f -> ...
  ...
```

the patterns don't agree on the variables they bind to: the first pattern binds to `i`, while the second binds to `f`.

In the second situation,

```
match ... with
  | A i | B i -> ...
  ...
```

the patterns don't agree on the type of values to bind to their variables: the first pattern binds a value of type `int` to `i`, while the second binds a value of type `float` to `i`.

The only way in which these two pattern can consistently bind to variables is not to bind to any variables at all:

```
match ... with
  | A _ | B _ -> ...
  ...
```

The complete example then becomes

```
type t = A of int | B of float

let f = function
  | A _ | B _ -> true
  | _ -> false
```

(But note that the last arm of the pattern match is superfluous as the first two pattern already exhaustively match all values of your type `t`. Hence, we get:

```
let f = function
  | A _ | B _ -> true
```

This of course is equivalent to writing `let f _ = true`.)

Answer (score 4):

In `Or` pattern (`|` pattern), you lose track of which constructors you are in. Therefore, you need to bind the same set of variables to work without referring to constructors.

And OCaml is strongly-typed; a value `i` cannot have both type `int` and type `float`.

If type `t` has more than two cases, you should write:

```
let f = function
        | A _ | B _ -> true
        | _ -> false
```

otherwise:

```
let f = function
        | A _ | B _ -> true
```

is enough since pattern matching is already exhaustive.

I agree that `Or` pattern is quite restrictive, but sometimes it is helpful when you have symmetric cases in your function:

```
type num = 
    | Int of int
    | Float of float

let add s1 s2 = 
    match s1, s2 with
    | Int i1, Int i2 -> Int (i1 + i2)
    | Int i, Float f | Float f, Int i -> Float (float i +. f)
    | Float f1, Float f2 -> Float (f1 +. f2)
```