# How do I Pattern-match GADT Types Get Alternative More Concrete Return Types?

Tags: ocaml, gadt, locally-abstract-type

I want to exploit GADT to implement the type `('a, 'b) liInstr_t` in order to hold various types of instructions which are recursively decoded into basic operations (if need be) that then executed. (Eventually, I should construct more abstract types over them but in a mechanical, compositional and scripted fashion.) Unfortunately, I have difficulties associating the locally abstract types from pattern-matching function argument with the alternative concrete return types desired for the GADT.

I believe I'm missing something fundamental or making wrong assumptions though I have looked at the ocaml 4.10.0 manual on [locally abstract types](https://v2.ocaml.org/releases/4.10/htmlman/locallyabstract.html) and [gadts](https://v2.ocaml.org/releases/4.10/htmlman/gadts.html), the [Real world Ocaml](https://dev.realworldocaml.org/gadts.html) book, and the responses to similar questions such as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69144536/in-ocaml-what-is-the-difference-between-a-and-type-a-and-when-to-use-eac) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58964775/pattern-matching-on-a-gadt-fails/58974684#58974684). This is because I seem to follow their explanations but cannot somehow apply them to my task.

From the above, I understand that polymorphic type variables annotate functions so that they can take on (be unified with) arbitrary types compatible with their constraints, and that locally abstract types let us have different types along alternative paths through a pattern-matching expression, say. Also, the local abstract types cannot be unified but can be refined to concrete types compatible with GADT result types. As such, GADTs can recurse over polymorphic types, and aggregate multiple result types into a single sum type.

I deliberately let the type `('a, 'b) liInstr_t` have two type variables (so I can add more later), and its variants capture various constraint formats and scenarios I may have to use together.

```
type
  liLabel_t = string        (* Instruction name (label) *)
and
  context_t = string        (* TODO: execution context *)
and
  'a context_list_t = 'a list
and
  'a liChooser_t = 'a -> int    (* get index of i-th list entry *)
and
  ('a, 'b) liInstr_t =
    LiExec: 'a -> ('a, 'b) liInstr_t        (* executable operation *)
  | LiExecTRY: ('a, _) liInstr_t        (* Ignore: Experiment on GADT *)
  | LiLab: liLabel_t -> ('a, 'b) liInstr_t  (* instruction label *)
  | LiLabTRY: (liLabel_t, _) liInstr_t      (* Ignore: Experiment on GADT *)
  | LiSeq: 'a liChooser_t * 'b list -> ('a, 'b) liInstr_t   (* sequence *)
  | LiAlt: 'a liChooser_t * 'b list -> ('a, 'b) liInstr_t   (* choice *)
  | LiLoop: 'a liChooser_t * 'b list -> ('a, 'b) liInstr_t  (* loop *)
  | LiName: 'a liChooser_t * liLabel_t * 'b context_list_t ->
    ('a, 'b) liInstr_t              (* change context *)
  | Err_LiInstr: ('a, 'b) liInstr_t     (* error handling *)
  | Nil_LiInstr: ('a, 'b) liInstr_t     (* no action *)
```

After experimenting, the sample function used is:

```
let ft1:  type  b c. (b, c) liInstr_t -> b = function
(* *)  | LiExec n -> n
(* *)  | LiExecTRY -> "4"
(* *)  | LiLab s -> "LiLab" 
(* *)  | LiLabTRY -> "LiLabTRY"
(* *)  | LiSeq (f, il) -> "LiSeq" 
(* *)  | LiAlt (f, il) -> "LiAlt" 
(* *)  | LiLoop (f, il) -> "LiLoop"
(* *)  | LiName (f, il, ic) -> "LiName"
(* *)  | Err_LiInstr -> "Err_LiInstr"
(* *)  | Nil_LiInstr -> "Nil_LiInstr"
;;
```

and it gave the error:

```
Line 3, characters 22-25:
3 | (* *)  | LiExecTRY -> "4"
                          ^^^
Error: This expression has type string but an expression was expected of type
         b
```

I still got errors when I changed the function annotation (and typing), or commented out some alternatives in the function pattern matching and the GADT type variants. Some of the errors (elided for brevity) were obtained as follows:

Using an extra locally-typed variable:

```
let ft1 :  type b c d. (b, c) liInstr_t -> d = function ...
2 | (* *)  | LiExec n -> n
                         ^
Error: This expression has type b but an expression was expected of type d
```

Using only polymorphic type variables:

```
let ft1:  'b 'c. ('b, 'c) liInstr_t -> 'b = function ...

Error: This definition has type 'c. (liLabel_t, 'c) liInstr_t -> liLabel_t
       which is less general than 'b 'c. ('b, 'c) liInstr_t -> 'b
```

My questions then are the following:

1. How can we capture and use the abstract types identified with alternative paths? A locally abstract type should bind (or be refined) to compatible concrete type(s) for values found in the resulting expression, or can be ignored, right? *Ignoring recursion*, this example:

> ```
> let rec eval : type a. a term -> a = function
>   | Int n    -> n                 (* a = int *)
>   | Add      -> (fun x y -> x+y)  (* a = int -> int -> int *)
>   | App(f,x) -> (eval f) (eval x)
>           (* eval called at types (b->a) and b for fresh b *)
> ```

on expression evaluation in the ocaml manual seems to suggest that is the case, at least for a 1-parameter GADT type. So, why aren't my types `b` and `c` not suitably bound (or refined) in the return type? And if they are binding (or being refined), which should bind to abstract type `b` and which to `c`, if at all? How can I find values for my return type so they can correctly associate with the *abstract*, *value-less* types reaching them. For, there is seems no way to obtain a result that has the type `b` in my first error above!

2. Why am I forced to have the same result type for the alternative paths to succeed (string type in my examples) whereas all possible result types of the GADT should be admissible. In this regard, the first variant (`LiExec n -> n`) seemed forced to have type string! Also, the abstract types and polymorphic variables along execution paths seem irrelevant to the result type!

I could not reproduce it but at one point, making the first variant `LiExec n -> 4` seemed to require integer return values from all alternative pattern matches. If indeed this is the case, why should abstract types on alternative paths require values from the same non-GADT return type? (This behaviour is of non-polymorphic types, right?)

3. To work around incomprehensible issues on polymorphic types and locally abstract types, is there a simple way to mix them in a constraint? Various permutations to mix them always seem to result in a syntax error. e.g.:

```
let ft1: (type d)  'b 'c. ('b, 'c) liInstr_t -> d = function
          ^^^^
Error: Syntax error
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In brief, the type `li_Instr_t` as defined is not an interesting GADT and it can be rewritten to the strictly equivalent ADT

```
type  ('a, 'b) liInstr_t =
  | LiExec of 'a
  | LiExecTRY
  | LiLab of liLabel_t
  | LiLabTRY
  | LiSeq of 'a liChooser_t * 'b list 
  | LiAlt of 'a liChooser_t * 'b list
  | LiLoop of 'a liChooser_t * 'b list
  | LiName of 'a liChooser_t * liLabel_t * 'b context_list_t
  | Err_LiInstr
  | Nil_LiInstr
```

because the type declaration never introduces equations (or existential quantifications) between the result type and the constructor of the GADT.

If we look at a simple example for GADT:

```ml
type ('elt,'array) compact_array =
| String: (char, String.t) compact_array
| Float_array: (float, Float.Array.t) compact_array
| Standard: ('a, 'a array) compact_array

let init: type elt array.
  (elt,array) compact_array -> int -> (int -> elt) -> array = 
fun kind n f -> match kind with
| String -> String.init n f
| Float_array -> Float.Array.init n f
| Standard -> Array.init n f
```

The difference is that the constructor `String` constrains the type of `compact_array` to be `(char,string) compact_array`. Thus, when I observe `String` in the pattern matching above, I can introduce the equation
`elt`=`char` and `array`=`string` in the branch `String` and use those equation locally . Similarly, after observing the constructor `Float_array` in the pattern matching, I can work with the equation `elt`=`float` and `array`=`Float.Array.t` inside the corresponding branch.

Contrarily, with the definition of `liInstr_t` as it stands, observing a constructor of a value of type `('a,'b) liInstr_t` brings no information on the type `('a,'b) liInstr_t`. Consequently, the  function `ft1` of type `type a b. (a,b) liInstr_t -> b` is is promising to return a `float array` when called with `ft1 (LiExecTRY:('a,float array) li_Instr_t)`. More generally, a function of type `a b. (a,b) liInstr_t` -> a`where no constructor impose a constraint on`b`is necessarily returning some value of type`b`that was contained inside`(a,b) liInstr_t` (or is not returning).

Using that knowledge, we can update your type `liInstr_t` to make the function `ft1` works by adding the equations corresponding to the expected return type for `ft1` to the definition of the type:

```ml
type liLabel_t = string
and context_t = string
and 'a context_list_t = 'a list
and 'a liChooser_t = 'a -> int
and ('a, 'b, 'ft1) liInstr_t =
| LiExec: 'a -> ('a, 'b,'a) liInstr_t    (* ft1 returns the argument of LiExec *)
 (* ft1 returns a string in all other cases *)
| LiExecTRY: ('a, 'b, string) liInstr_t   
| LiLab: liLabel_t -> ('a, 'b, string) liInstr_t 
| LiLabTRY: (liLabel_t, 'b, string) liInstr_t
| LiSeq: 'a liChooser_t * 'b list -> ('a,'b, string) liInstr_t
| LiAlt: 'a liChooser_t * 'b list -> ('a,'b, string) liInstr_t
| LiLoop: 'a liChooser_t * 'b list -> ('a,'b, string) liInstr_t
| LiName: 'a liChooser_t * liLabel_t * 'b context_list_t ->
    ('a,'b, string) liInstr_t
| Err_LiInstr: ('a, 'b, string) liInstr_t
| Nil_LiInstr: ('a, 'b, string) liInstr_t
```

and now that we have the right equation in place, we can define `ft1` as:

```ml
let ft1:  type  a b c. (a, b, c) liInstr_t -> c = function
| LiExec n -> n
| LiExecTRY -> "4"
| LiLab s -> "LiLab" 
| LiLabTRY -> "LiLabTRY"
| LiSeq (f, il) -> "LiSeq" 
| LiAlt (f, il) -> "LiAlt" 
| LiLoop (f, il) -> "LiLoop"
| LiName (f, il, ic) -> "LiName"
| Err_LiInstr -> "Err_LiInstr"
| Nil_LiInstr -> "Nil_LiInstr"
```

which typechecks without any error.

Comment: The non-introduction of equations in `('a,'b) liInstr_t` seems subtle, especially as type variables and their matching on use seem to be equational constraints. For example, from your paragraph "Contrarily, with ..." is not clear to me:
1. Is there some kind of partial ordering or subtyping over instantiations of type variables. If so, what are the rules?
2. Why would a function have type `a b. (a,b) liInstr_t -> a` be given type `b` values when it prefers type `a` ones?
3. Not clear what you mean by "(or is not returning)"? The function will not terminate?

Comment: 0. If you can transform your type to a non-GADT one, you were never introducing equation.
1. You never instantiate the parameter of the type in your definition.
2. I made a mistake I mean `(a,b) liInstr_t -> b`
3. let f x = assert false or let rec f x = f x

Comment: While I now better understand how to produce correct GADT, my second question is still an issue. It is still not clear to me: why were all my return types (except maybe for the first variant) compelled to be `string` (or `LiLabel_t`) *before being rejected later* for being less general than the return type `b`. (I must point out I sort of stumbled on the `string` type!) Is it because the argument to variant `LiLab` was `string`? If so, what is the reasoning within the typechecker?

Comment: "4" is a string. Thus the branch `| LiExecTRY -> "4"` returns a string whereas a value of type `b` (which is locally abstract type equals to no other type in the current scope) was expected.

Comment: Actually, changing the branch to `| LiExecTRY -> 4`, where the return type is `int`, gives the message `Error: This expression has type int but an expression was expected of type liLabel_t = string`. Similar errors are given for all the other branches (except `LiExec n -> n`) if their return type is not `string`. I don't even get to the message of having a less general type! Reason why I typed them all `string`.

Comment: Changing the branch to `| LiExecTRY -> 4` gives me `Error: This expression has type int but an expression was expected of type b`. Would you mind opening a new question with all errors that you don't understand? With locally abstract types, you never get a "less general type than ... " error message by design: if you wrote a function that typecheck for a fresh abstract type, then outside of the scope of the locally abstract type, the type of the function can be generalized. In other words, you are guaranteed to have a sufficient polymorphic function.

Comment: Many thanks. I have now posed the question as: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73192912/what-typing-logic-compels-me-to-have-the-same-return-types-for-gadt-function-alt.

Comment: This answer best addressed by problem. However, the answer from @Alan offered critical insight (on universal vs existential quantification from caller and callee perspectives) to grasp this solution. Also, the related question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73192912/what-typing-logic-compels-me-to-have-the-same-return-types-for-gadt-function-alt, which further explains existential quantification via locally abstract types in GADT function variants, helped me better grasp what is possible in GADTs as exploited in OCaml.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose we have the following GADT:

```ml
type _ simple_gadt =
  | Con : 'a -> 'a simple_gadt
```

The type signature of `Con` can be understood as `('a : Type) -> 'a -> 'a simple_gadt` (not real OCaml syntax); in other words, it takes a *type* as its first argument, and the rest of the type is *dependent* on this input type. The client provides the type; for example:

```ml
let value : int simple_gadt = Con 0
```

Implicitly, you can understand this definition as really meaning `let value = Con(type int, 0)`, where the type is given as an argument (again, not real OCaml syntax).

When you write a function that takes a `'a simple_gadt` as an argument, you don't know what `'a` is. `'a` is said to be an "existential type" provided by the *caller* of the function. Consider the following function:

```
let f (type a) (param : a simple_gadt) : a = match param with
  | Con x -> x
```

The type of `f` is `'a . 'a simple_gadt -> 'a`. A client can evaluate `f (Con 0)` and get back `0`, of type `int`. A client can also evaluate `f (Con true)` and get back `true`, of type `bool`. The definition of the function has no control over what the actual type `'a` is; only the caller does.

Suppose we attempt to define:

```
let g (type a) (param : a simple_gadt) : a = match param with
  | Con _ -> ""
```

One would be able to evaluate `g (Con 0)` and get back `""`, a `string`, but based on the type of `Con 0`, the output of the function should be an `int`. This is clearly a type error, so `g` has an ill-typed definition, and the compiler rightfully rejects it. Likewise, your definition

```ml
let ft1:  type  b c. (b, c) liInstr_t -> b = function
(* ... *)
(* *)  | LiExecTRY -> "4"
(* ... *)
```

is ill-typed because it assumes that `b` is `string`, while `b` could be any type that the caller provides. It looks like you have other similar type errors because you are attempting to pick more specific types for the existential types.

If the caller can choose any type, how can one use GADTs to "refine" the type variable to a more concrete type? The only way to do this is through the information that the caller provides.

Consider the following type definition:

```ml
type _ term =
  | Abs : ('a -> 'b) -> ('a -> 'b) term
  | App : ('a -> 'b) term * 'a term -> 'b term
  | Bool : bool -> bool term
```

In a GADT, each constructor can make the type parameters more specific. Therefore, by pattern matching against each constructor, a function can refine the existential type parameter.

Consider this function on the GADT defined above:

```ml
let rec eval : 'a . 'a term -> 'a =
  fun (type a) (term : a term) : a ->
  match term with
  | Abs f -> f
  | App(f, x) -> (eval f) (eval x)
  | Bool b -> b
```

In the `Abs f` case, `Abs f` is known to have type `('a -> 'b) term` for some `'a` and `'b` by the definition of `Abs`. Similar reasoning applies for the `App(f, x)` and `Bool b` cases.

What's a universally quantified type from the caller's perspective (i.e. the caller can pick any type) must be an existentially quantified type from the callee's perspective (i.e. the callee must work with some *fixed* arbitrary type that the caller provides).

Comment: The clarifying idea is perceiving the caller's universally quantified type as the callee's existentially quantified type. Hence the question: How is universal quantification over non-existing caller inputs handled to produce existentially quantified callee output?

Comment: To illustrate my preceding comment:
1. `LiExecTRY` takes no argument and so cannot ill-type. So, abstract type `b` can match `string` or any other type.
2. The single concrete type (`liLabel_t`) of `LiLab` existentially and uniquely matches abstract type `b`. So it must return `liLabel_t` (a `string` type).
3. `LiLabTRY` cannot ill-type on no argument. But its return type expects abstract type `b` to refine to `liLabel_t`! So we `b` refine to `liLabel_t` and ignore `c`?

Comment: The abstract type `b` matches *no* other types. Since `LiExecTRY: (a,b) liInstr_t` introduces neither a value of type `b` nor an equation on `b`, it means that it is not possible to return a value of the unknown (aka existentially quantiified) type `b` in the `LiExecTRY` branch.

Comment: Consider the GADT `type _ witness = Witness : 'a witness`. I can construct `let int_witness : int witness = Witness`. Notice that this term is not actually carrying an `int`!

Suppose we attempt to define `let f : type a. a witness -> a = function Witness -> true`. Then, I could have `f int_witness` give the type `int` to the term `""`! So, just because the constructor doesn't actually contain a subterm of the type variable doesn't mean that the callee can pick any type. The compiler correctly rejects `f`. The caller still chooses the type.

Comment: @Alan I get the argument you are making; function `f` could make an integer of Boolean value `true`. However, where can term `""` be introduced in function `f` as given?